# Django: django-facebook redirects to /facebook/connect/

Tags: django, facebook, redirect, django-settings, django-facebook

I read all the documentation about django-facebook, and I'm still not understanding why after setup the settings.py, the registration redirects to a template on django-facebook.

settings.py

```
FACEBOOK_LOGIN_DEFAULT_REDIRECT = '/profile/'
FACEBOOK_REGISTRATION_BACKEND = 'django_facebook.registration_backends.UserenaBackend'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile/'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'userena.backends.UserenaAuthenticationBackend',
    'django_facebook.auth_backends.FacebookBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',

)
```

The template shouldn't be editable on templates folder at my app?
There is something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the template loader priority, I think. Try to list your custom app before the django-facebook in your settings INSTALLED_APPS and you should get the right template.